# With Javascript, how to read what is within <span> tags, when the value is created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and I basically want it to read what is created in between the `<span>` tags (that value is created by another javascript script), and then take that to display 'article' or 'articles'.

```
<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var q = document.getElementById('quantity');

if (q == 1) {
    document.write("article");
}
else
  {
  document.write("articles");
  }
</script>
```

So I want it to check `<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>`, and if the value that is present is '1', write 'article' and if the value is '0' or more than '1' write 'articles'. I hope you can get it.

Now it works, but only if you actually write something in between the `<span>`, like: 
    1

But the value is created externally and the script must be able to read the value that is created when the page is loaded right?

The result should be a sentence that says 'You have x article(s) in your shopping cart'.

I have no idea of how I should do this, I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dont. Ever. Use. `document.write()`. Forget that that function exists. It isn't the function you are looking for.

Comment: I'm very new to Javscript and programming. How could I do somethinhg like this?

Comment: Set a timeout using `setTimeout` and execute it after you know that the value has definitely been set. You can get `q` by `var q = document.getElementById('quantity');`

Comment: Since the content is already generated externally, can't you also apply correct pluralisation at that point?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Using a timer for determining things is like gambling.

Comment: I've editted my code and now use var q = document.getElementById('quantity'); trying to figure out how to set a timer but I don't know if this is the best idea.

Comment: @FredrikPortström I'd assume that OP would check if it was '', and if it was, execute yet another `setTimeout`, but you're right - that didn't reflect on my answer.

Comment: Why do you want format this number with Javascript? This seems like a typical problem that should be handled on server side.

Comment: I just don't know how to do this ;p I want the code to take the value of <span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> (wich will be a number like '0' or '7') and display 'article' if the number is '1'. If the number is '0' or '6' for example I want it to display 'articles'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>
<!-- ... --->
<span id="quantityText"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity"),
        quantityText = document.getElementById("quantityText");

    if (parseInt(quantity.innerHTML, 10) === 1) {
        quantityText.innerHTML = "article";
    } else {
        quantityText.innerHTML = "articles";
    }
</script>
```

Note that you must use a [radix argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (10, in this case) to make sure numbers are interpreted as base10. Otherwise everything starting with `'0x'` would be interpreted as hexadecimal (base16), for example.

alternative syntax using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity"),
        quantityText = document.getElementById("quantityText"),
        quantityValue = parseInt(quantity.innerHTML, 10);

    quantityText.innerHTML = "article" + (quantityValue === 1 ? "" : "s");
</script>
```

Comment: I wouldn't agree that you must use a radix argument. The question contains no requirement of treating texts beginning with “0x”. Instead of parseInt (“parseInt(quantity.innerHTML, 10)”), just use the unary plus operator (“+quantity.innerHTML”).

Comment: The unary plus has problems of its own. If you want to do quick and stable int conversion, use `~~`. In any case: Yes, you must use a radix argument for `parseInt()`. Maybe it's not technically required in this particular situation, but that doesn't mean you don't have to use it. The reason is simple: If you bargain to save typing `, 10` in *this* situation, you will forget it in a situation where it really matters. Consequently the smart thing is to always use it.

Comment: The radix argument **never** matters, except extremely rare exceptional cases, so I would rather encourage saving three bytes. Go for the unary plus. `~~` is also good.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, this code looks better. But the main problem is still occuring: the value in between <span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> is not seen because it gets created in an external file (simpleCart.js). It now always displays 'articles'.

Comment: @Fredrik `parseInt('0x10') !== parseInt('10')`. Of course the radix argument matters (otherwise there wouldn't be one, right?). Also: Saving three bytes? Seriously? What's that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @Owen: *When* does it get created? It's all a matter of running the above *after* the other routine is done.

Comment: @Tomalak It gets created when someone adds a product to their basket (on another page where simplecart.js). Then, on this quantity page the same javascript file (simplecart.js) is included in the header. (By the way: the shopping cart code works fine)

Comment: @Tomalak What's the radix argument supposed to accomplish? There's nothing saying that parsing `"0x10"` as 0 is more right than parsing it as 16, and it doesn't even matter, as the argument will **never** be `"0x10"`. In this case we don't even need to parse anything. Complete solution: `<script>document.getElementById("quantityText").innerHTML = "article" + (document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML == 1 ? "" : "s")</script>`

Comment: @Fredrik It's not about what result is "more right". It's about defensive programming and being conscious about what results to expect from a function call. *"But in this situation...!"* is not a valid counter-argument. To answer your question: Its supposed to accomplish heightening the awareness that `parseInt()` does not always what one would naively think it does.

Comment: @Owen Well, if some code that sets the contents of an HTML element is included in the header, make your code runs *after that* - by including it later. (For example at the end of the body. Not nice, but since you are a beginner... one step at a time.)

Answer (score -1):

In addition to pure javascript, you can also use jQuery:

```
   jQuery($this).find('span.simpleCart_quantity') // find the span with class name: simpleCart_quantity
   .text() // get the text
```

Comment: The OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for reminder, I just added more explanation in the text.